# How can i change selected option background?

Tags: html, css, select

I want to change selected option background

My code still doesn't work according to the documentation!

[How to change the background color of a select option on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232273/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-select-option-on-hover)

, [Change select box option background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color)

,etc.

I try:

```css
select {
    width: 200px;
}
        
option:checked {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
<body>

    <select onfocus='this.size=3;' onblur='this.size=0;'
    onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change select box option background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color)